# Change the position of a text in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I just started a programing in course in android studio using Java and XML and cant really figure out how to do a simple task. I have 3 buttons at the top of the screen, they fill up the whole width of the screen. I want to add a text below these 3 buttons, but i dont really now how to specify this. Right now i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_textcolor" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_textsize" />

<TextView
    android:text="South Africa"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the text in the text element is displayed at the right side of the screen, its barely visible. The text gets cramped up so tight that it gets misaligned verticaly. What would i do if i instead wanted the text inside the textview element to be displayed just below the 3 buttons, to the left horizontaly, like normal text?

Thank you!

Comment: you will have to share a screenshot or so to explain your current problem..

Comment: Have you declared the orientation of your layout? The default orientation is horizontal and will result in all the buttons and the TextView to be rendered next to each other

Comment: I have horizontal because i have not declared anything else, i understand that this is why the text gets placed to the right. But the thing is that i want the buttons to be using a horizontal layout but not the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. There are also many other layouts you can try. Check here for the [other type of available layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

> RelativeLayout lets child views specify their position relative to the
>   parent view or to each other (specified by ID). So you can align two
>   elements by right border, or make one below another, centered in the
>   screen, centered left, and so on. By default, all child views are
>   drawn at the top-left of the layout, so you must define the position
>   of each view using the various layout properties available from
>   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: Thank you, so i put relativelayout instead of linear layout. Now, all the buttons are squishied together. Do you recommend using paddingLeft to place them where i want?

Comment: use combination of `leftof`, `rightof` and `padding`

Comment: you could also use `alignLeft` to align to the view on top or bottom

Comment: Or can i just use the horizontal layout for the buttons and declare a relativelayout for the text? Because using linear layout, the buttons are where i want them to be.

Comment: Yes that should be OK too... But avoid too many layouts. Relative is great once u get a hang of it. Will take a few minutes.

Comment: Okay thank you for the tips. I will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_textcolor" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_textsize" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="South Africa"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This made my app scale perfectly trough different devices, thank you alot haha. But it was not what i was asking for!

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this. Inside the **TextView** tag add:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/buttonid"
```

Obviously you have to use relative layout for using this